# How to increase polygon count when I export Graphics3D object as STL file?

Tags: graphics3d, export, mesh

I am trying to make a sphere for CFD simulation, the sphere looks well in notebook of Mathematica, Like this:
[image]

but when I export it as stl file and open the file again it looks so rough, like this:
[image]

so, How can I increase polygon count or improve the quality of stl file in Mathematica?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.05}]
```

[image: discretized sphere]

```
MeshCellCount[s, 2] (* count the number of triangles used *)
   20640

Export["sphere.stl", s];
```

Comment: It does work！ but when i have a complex 3D object , such as the combination of two cylinders, it is difficult to express the region.

Comment: That should be a separate question, I would say.